# Divi portfolio title on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm wondering whats wrong with the code. I created a custom hover effect for divi portfolio module and its working fine until you hover on the image or the overlay, but as soon as you hover on the title, the image responds.

Please check and Help me guys. My code on custom hover. Hover on the title to see the issue. [Check this link](http://visualgarage.wearenakshatra.com/)

```
.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_overlay{
   height:80px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity:1;
   top:inherit;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   transition:transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,80px,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,80px,0);
   z-index: 555;
}

.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_pb_portfolio_item h2{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 30px;
   text-transform: none;
   z-index: 556;
   font-size: 90%;
   overflow:hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,50px,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,50px,0);
}

.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_portfolio_image img {
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden; 
} 
.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_portfolio_image:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-30px,0); 
   transform: translate3d(0,-30px,0); 
} 

.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_pb_portfolio_item:hover h2{ 
   opacity: 1; 
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
} 

.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_pb_portfolio_item:hover .et_overlay {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
} 

.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_pb_portfolio_item{ overflow:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_pb_portfolio_item h2 {
   pointer-events: none; 
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, with pointer events set to none, this wont cause any other problems?

Comment: Theoretically, it does. The `<a>` in that `<h2>` will no longer receive any pointer events (clicks). But in practice, all its events will pass down to what's beneath it. And that's an image wrapped in another anchor, with the same link. So no, in practice nothing will change.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, for the solution and the brief explanation.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to change the `.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_portfolio_image:hover img` selector with `.et_pb_portfolio_0 .et_portfolio_item:hover img` in your code, but I can't tell you exactly where, as you (or the theme) are using an optimizer plugin which minifies it. If it's not your code and it's part of Divi, you shouldn't touch it. You're welcome.

Comment: I thought so, that's why I said it. It's healthier to move the `:hover` on the container. What I initially proposed, while effective, is after all, *disabling* functionality. Hence, inherently wrong. A hack which happens not to have adverse effects in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks again, Its working good. I need to learn more from you. How can I keep in touch?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to insert your h2 tag inside the "et_portfolio_image" class span tag. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Changing markup structure in premium themes is not as easy as it seems. That markup's generated.